# AWS Lambda send image file to Amazon Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have the next problem, I try send image file in base64 to Lambda function(write in Python), for invoke Sagemaker Endpoint, this is my Lambda Function:

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import json
import base64

# grab environment variables
ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data['foto']
    img = base64.b64decode(payload)
    #body = json.dumps({"instances": img})

    try:
        response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                            Body=img)
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Inference Error:")
        print(e)

    return { "img":"ok" }
```

And sagemaker endpoint invoke in Jupyter works fine with this code,

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('./data/val', target_size=(224,224))

instance = test_generator[1][0]
print(instance.shape)
array = instance.reshape((1,) + instance.shape)
payload = { 'instances': array.tolist() }

resp = tf_predictor.predict(payload)['predictions']
print(resp)
```

The error in Lambda says that the data type is unknown, and CloudWatch error in dimensions.

I think, that the error is in Body of invoke_endpoint method, but i not found how convert bytes type to list with image data. I need custom Lambda Function with numpy, or other library? or isn't necesary

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking the Lambda function? If you are using API Gateway to pass the image data to the SageMaker Runtime endpoint, you may need to set the contentHandling properties on the integration to handle binary encoding. See here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Comment: I pass the base64 string in a JSON file and extract with Lambda, in this case I need this?

Comment: Thanks, was unclear on your architecture - if you are not using API Gateway to invoke the Lambda function, disregard that previous comment. In order to isolate the underlying issue, see if you can invoke the SageMaker Runtime invokeEndpoint API directly - see here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html#SageMakerRuntime.Client.invoke_endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Solution it simple
Convert base64 to bytes with `bytes(img)` and add `ContentType='image/jpeg'` to the invoke endpoint.

After two small changes, This is how your Lambda function should look now:

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import json
import base64

# grab environment variables
ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data['foto']
    img = base64.b64decode(payload)
    
    payload = bytes(img) # convert base64 to bytes 

    try:
        response = runtime.invoke_endpoint
        (
            EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
            ContentType='image/jpeg' ,
            Body=payload
        )
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Inference Error:")
        print(e)

    return {"img": "ok"}
```