# AWS send image to Sagemaker from Lambda: how to set content handling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

similar question to
[AWS Lambda send image file to Amazon Sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66683538/6896705)

I try to make simple-mnist work (the model was built by referring to [aws tutorial](https://sagemaker-immersionday.workshop.aws/en/lab3/option1.html))

Then I am using API gateway (REST API w/ proxy integration) to post image data to lambda, and would like to send it to sagemaker endpoint and make an inference.

In lambda function, I wrote the code(.py) like this.

```py
runtime = boto3.Session().client('sagemaker-runtime')

endpoint_name = 'tensorflow-training-YYYY-mm-dd-...'
res = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,
                              Body=Image,
                              ContentType='image/jpeg',
                              Accept='image/jpeg')
```

However, when I send image to lambda via API gateway, this error occurs.

> [ERROR] ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the
> InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from model with
> message " {
> "error": "Unsupported Media Type: image/jpeg" }

I think I need to do something referring to [Working with binary media types for REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html)

But since I am very new, I have no idea about the appropriate thing to do, on which page (maybe API Gateway page?) or how...

I need some clues to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/adapt-inference-container.html) you can see that only some specific content types are supported by default, and images are not in this list. I think you have to either implement your `input_fn` function or adapt your data to one of the supported content types.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. [This page](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container/blob/master/README.md#prepost-processing) tells the same thing. I guess I need to convert 'image' to 'json' type, but I do not get the desired result (mostly "JSON Parse error: Invalid value." error occurs). I would appreciate any help.. (maybe I should raise another question?)

Comment: yes I think it's better to raise another specific question